# Double class method within class

Tags: java

Why did the designers of the `Double` class decide to make the method `parseDouble()` `static`? is this only because it is easier to call it directly with the class?

Comment: Because parsing a string has nothing to do with the state of any particular instance of `Double`.

Comment: In Java, when you see `static`, think "stateless function".

Comment: so by stateless you mean no object is instantiated??? it is just directly called

Comment: Exactly. `static` methods do not require any instance of the class to be called; they are called by `ClassName.staticMethod()` instead of `instanceName.method()`. `static` methods really only need whatever parameters are passed into them to execute and will behave the same way every time they are called ("stateless").

Answer (score 3):

The function is independent of the state of any particular Double, so it's meaningless to attach it to a particular instance like that.

Comment: No. `parseDouble()` returns a `double`, which is a primitive value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Double::parseDouble` returns a `double` not a `Double`.

`double` is a primitive type so in this way you have both choices available:

```
Double boxed = Double.parseDouble("10.0"); // semantically equivalent to new Double("10.0f")
double unboxed = Double.parseDouble(10.0f);
```

The first case will box the `double` value inside a `Double` object but the latter won't, thus you are saving an object allocation on the heap.

Comment: You are leaking a bit of C++ syntax when you say `::` ;-)

Comment: Java 8 now references methods with the C++ `::` syntax. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: Also, your first line is more idiomatically expressed as `Double boxed = new Double("10.0");`

Comment: @Nayuki: indeed, but actually since Java8 that's how you refer to a method when using it with methods that accept functional interfaces so that's not true anymore!

Comment: @Nayuki Actually, it's `Double.valueOf("10.0")`.  The difference is that if you call `new Double("10.0")` three times, you will create three distinct objects, but if you call `Double.valueOf("10.0")` three times, you will (probably) create three references to the same object.

Comment: The problem is: You are right about the return type, but this answer does not explain why the method is static? Maybe you can clarify how you think returning a `double` is the reason why the method is static?

Comment: @RAnders00: It seems clear to me, primitive types doesn't have methods, nor constructors and here you are generating a double from a String, how would you attach it to an object instance?

Comment: @Jack This is correct, but the answer does not state this. Maybe it can be included? You are probably so progressed in Java (like most here) that what you told me in the comments is obvious to you and you think that everyone already knows this.